# nginx nested location fallthrough

Tags: nginx

I need to enforce trailing slashes on a particular set of URIs on my site.

The URIs take the following format: `/foo/bar1/bar2/bar3/?abc`, where `/foo/` is common across all dynamic and also a valid URI on it's own.

All and only dynamic URIs will match the regex `^(.*[^/])$` assuming a prefix check on `/foo/` was performed.

My code currently looks like this:

```
location /foo/ {
  location ~* ^(.*[^/])$ {
    return 302 $baseUrl/$1/$is_args$args;
  }
}
```

This, however, causes 404s on all `/foo/.*`, though it does successfully insert the slash as intended.

Clearly, if it matches the outer location, but not the inner one, it fails.

What I'm looking for then, is a statement that causes the execution to step back out of outer location.

Note:

I realize I could just say

```
location ~* ^(/foo/.*[^/])$ {
  return 302 $baseUrl/$1/$is_args$args;
}
```

but I'd like to avoid it because of the performance hit of regex. Don't want to deal with that on non-candidate pages.

Comment: How are the URIs with a trailing `/` processed. Couldn't you just include that within the `location` block. You either need to duplicate the code or use a regular expression.

Comment: @RichardSmith, it looks like duplicating code was the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research and experimentation, I ended up moving this condition into the final

```
location / {
   try files  . . .
}
```

to get  something like

```
location / {
  ## Enforce trailing slash on dynamic pages
  location /foo/ {
    location ~* ^(.*[^/])$ {
      return 302 $baseUrl/$1/$is_args$args;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Still a bit messy and having duplicate code, but it works